# How to display json string in Listview in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-activity, android-listview

my question is how to display an json strings in listview in android and when click on any then go to the selected activity...
 the format of webservice is something like....

```
abcd,test
xyz,test1
tyui,test2
yuuhh,test3
abc,test4
```

this what my webservice is returning now i want to add it in listview of android.
I make one adapter class and other is activity class for this.
and when i click on any then it will got o the selected activity.

Suppose, If I click on test1 then activity Test1 typeA else if test test4 then activity test4 type... is selected

Comment: Answer received is not in proper JSON Format, are you aware of that? OK. When you have a JSON then you'll can fill an `ArrayList` object. With that object you can create an `ArrayAdapter` and assign it to the `ListView`. Done.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing is come in my mind for this... actually this just strings not any json array and other type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you posted is not in `JSON` format. Example of json data can be like this-
    String json =

```
{
  "array": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

You can create an `JSONObject` from this string as-

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

You can get `JSONArray` as-

```
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("array");
```

You can get the objects of the array over a loop.
You can get the number as

```
int number = jsonObject.getInt("number");
```

and so on the rest data.

**Edit**
Once you get the data you can create the `ArrayList<String>` and then an `ArrayAdapter` and you can set the adapter to the `ListView`;